# How can I add this unallocated space to my partition?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

How can I add this unallocated space to my partition?

[image: Screenshot of partitions using Gparted]

I am using Gparted when booting from a Ubuntu 15.10 CD

I have 74.99 GB unallocated storage. I want to add that storage to my ext4 partition (/dev/sda5)

However, when I try to click resize on ext4, I get a maximum size of it that is not much more than its current size. I. e. the GUI shows a maximum size limit just around 28 GB and I don't know how to actually add the 74.99 GB.

Advice appreciated.

Comment: The extended partition `/dev/sda4` is a "container" for the logical partitions 5 and 6, so you need to resize it first. (The reason you can't resize 5 is that it must stay inside 4.)

Comment: But /dev/sda4 appears to be mounted when I boot from Live Ubuntu CD. I. e. the resize option is greyed out.

Comment: Maybe you need to unmount sda6 as well.

Answer (score 0):

with gparted you will need to move `/dev/sda4` up to fill that unallocated space . if you cant directly move it just make note of the exact size ... then you can stretch it out so it takes up the full unallocated space then shrink it so its the same original size .. that should put the free space between `/devsda4` and `/dev/sda5` .. then you should be able to expand 5 to the full space .. or very close too it.. it may end up leaving a few meg of unallocated.